# Prevent all Access Form ListBoxes from updating

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have a form that gets populated with rows of data from a database. I want to add a listbox to each row for the user to select a letter grade. When I run the form all the data **looks** correct, but if I update a single listbox all the listboxes in the form update to the same value. It seems like the listboxes aren't independent of each other.

Comment: You're better post your code sono as to let us have a clearer picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unbound control will always display the same on all records.

For individual display, you must bind it to a field of the record - or redesign your form in some way.